# Memory allocation problem when running Random forest regression in python

Tags: python, pandas, regression, random-forest, scikit-learn

I have image with 4 bands . I want to see if I can predict the first band using the 3 other bands.
My problem is that  I cannot fit the model because I get the following error message:

> **MemoryError: could not allocate 469762048 bytes**

I thought that maybe I can break the image into subsets and then to run the algorithm , based on this post
[memoryerror in Supervised Random Forest Classification in Python sklearn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247901/memoryerror-in-supervised-random-forest-classification-in-python-sklearn)

but I get stuck after the part of creating "flat_pixels".

in my script, i'm using train_test_split in order to predict the data, so I have X_train,X_test,y_train, _y_test. In the given example, the write create the flat_pixels but seems like it doesn't keep the y values . Also, seems like he doesn't have the "fit" part.

This is what I did:

```
#load image

img=rasterio.open("myImage.tif")

array=img.read()

#create pandas df
df_all=pd.DataFrame(array.reshape([4,-1]).T)
df_all.columns=['band1','band2','band3','band4']
df_all=df_all.reset_index()
df_all

#create index column in order to keep the original index number
df = df_all.dropna(how='any',axis=0)
df.columns=['index','band1','band2','band3','band4']

#define x,y
X = df.iloc[:, 2:]
#y is band 1
y = df.iloc[:,1:2]

#split the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

here I have tried to split it into subsets in order to reduce the memory allocationsaccording to the post here [memoryerror in Supervised Random Forest Classification in Python sklearn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247901/memoryerror-in-supervised-random-forest-classification-in-python-sklearn)  but it seems to me like i'm losing the y values and then how can I predict it?

```
#convert to numpy

np_X_train=X_train.to_numpy()
np_X_test=X_test.to_numpy()
np_y_train=y_train.to_numpy()
np_y_test=y_test.to_numpy()


#from the post

flat_pixels = np_X_train.reshape(len(np_X_train),3)
flat_pixels_subsets = np.array_split(flat_pixels, 50)
```

My end goal: I would like to break my image into subsets in order to be able to fit my model and create prediction.
Any other olution to deal with the memoryError that is not through breaking into subsets is welcome as well.